# Geom_segment not reading missing aesthetics: x, y, xend and yend Piper Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, geom-segment

I am trying to reproduce the Piper plot here: https://github.com/markolipka/ggplot_Piper however I keep getting the error:
*Error: geom_segment requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y, xend and yend*
despite x, y, xend and yend being specified in the code:
https://pastebin.pl/view/3a5dfd01

Has anyone utilized this Piperplot code before? Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I need to remove or add?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the code that's giving you problems as text, not as a picture. I can't copy/paste the code from your picture and debug it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell without a reproducible example.

Try the following:

```
b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

df <- data.frame(x1 = 2.62, x2 = 3.57, y1 = 21.0, y2 = 15.0)

b +
 geom_curve(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2, colour = "curve"), data = df) +
 geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2, colour = "segment"), data = df)
```

If it works, then my bet would be that you have a problem with your dataframe. May be your variables does not exist or are in the wrong format.
It it does not work, then you probably will have to install again ggplot.